# Full screen image slider is repeating after taking time

Tags: html, css

```css
.slideshow {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 0;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.slideshow li {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  background-repeat: none;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 0;
  animation: imageAnimation 60s linear infinite;
}

.slideshow li:nth-child(1) {
  background-image: url("https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_fjords.jpg")
}

.slideshow li:nth-child(2) {
  background-image: url("https://cloud.netlifyusercontent.com/assets/344dbf88-fdf9-42bb-adb4-46f01eedd629/68dd54ca-60cf-4ef7-898b-26d7cbe48ec7/10-dithering-opt.jpg");
  animation-delay: 10s;
}

.slideshow li:nth-child(3) {
  background-image: url("https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/06/18/17/42/image-1465348_1280.jpg");
  animation-delay: 20s;
}

.slideshow li:nth-child(4) {
  background-image: url("http://eskipaper.com/images/image-2.jpg");
  animation-delay: 30s;
}

@keyframes imageAnimation {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  }
  10% {
    opacity: 1;
    animation-timing-function: ease-out;
  }
  20% {
    opacity: 1
  }
  30% {
    opacity: 0
  }
}

.no-cssanimations .slideshow li {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<ul class="slideshow">
  <li>
    <span>""</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span>""</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span>""</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span>""</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I have attached my CSS and HTML code. After 5.jpeg is displayed a blank page is displayed for sometime and then slider starts repeating again.I want to have a continuous repeating slides of images without break.There may be some error in my code.Since i am new to web desgining please help me out.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
.slideshow li{
    animation: imageAnimation 40s linear infinite;
}
```

As you can see above, I changed `60s` to `40s`, that's what's causing temporary white background.

**UPDATE:**

As we can see the 2nd `animation-delay` starts after `10s`, 3rd after `20s` and 4th after `30s`.

If the total time in `animation` is `60s`, then for the 4th animation total duration for the transaction to occur is `30s` i.e. from 30th second to 60th second.

This is the reason, you were getting the white screen after 4th image.

```css
.slideshow {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 0;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.slideshow li {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  background-repeat: none;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 0;
  animation: imageAnimation 40s linear infinite;
}

.slideshow li:nth-child(1) {
  background-image: url("https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_fjords.jpg")
}

.slideshow li:nth-child(2) {
  background-image: url("https://cloud.netlifyusercontent.com/assets/344dbf88-fdf9-42bb-adb4-46f01eedd629/68dd54ca-60cf-4ef7-898b-26d7cbe48ec7/10-dithering-opt.jpg");
  animation-delay: 10s;
}

.slideshow li:nth-child(3) {
  background-image: url("https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/06/18/17/42/image-1465348_1280.jpg");
  animation-delay: 20s;
}

.slideshow li:nth-child(4) {
  background-image: url("http://eskipaper.com/images/image-2.jpg");
  animation-delay: 30s;
}

@keyframes imageAnimation {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  }
  10% {
    opacity: 1;
    animation-timing-function: ease-out;
  }
  20% {
    opacity: 1
  }
  30% {
    opacity: 0
  }
}

.no-cssanimations .slideshow li {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<ul class="slideshow">
  <li>
    <span>""</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span>""</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span>""</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span>""</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: What is the difference between my code and the code provided by you?My issue is with the displaying of blank page for sometime after fourth image Is displayed.i want to have a continuous slides of image without displaying blank page.

Comment: Can you tell why was that happening? Please